# Shell Scripting for archiving and encrypting

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I need to create a script which receives from the CLI the name of a file with the extension .tar.gz and a folder(e.g ./archivator.sh box.tar.gz MyFolder). This script will archive the files from the folder(only the files WITHIN the folder and without any compression) and they will be moved into the archive received as a parameter. The archive will be then encrypted(using the aescrypt) with the password 'apple'.

OS: Debian 6

**Note: The final encrypted archive will have the same name as the first given parameter.**

What i have tried so far is this:

```
tar -cvf $1 $2/* | aescrypt -e -p apple - > $1.aes | mv $1.aes $1
```

And this is what I receive when I am trying to check my script:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with a failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: Works well on Linux (archlinux) with GNU tar 1.26

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
tar cf - $2/* | aescrypt -e -p apple - > $1
```

`-` here, means **STDIN**

Works well on Linux (archlinux) with GNU tar 1.26

If it doesn't work, run the script in debug mode:

```
bash -x script.sh
```

then come again to post the output.

Comment: What is your OS, versions of OS and tools ? Add this infos in your post.

Comment: + aescrypt -e -p apple -
+ tar cf - folder/1 folder/2 folder/3

Comment: @user1868906 : what are you telling us here? This answer should work. If this is a change in your requirements for your script processing, then please update your question with a clear text explanation and possibly 2-3 example inputs. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

After a little research, here is the solution:

```
pushd $2
tar cvf $1 .
openssl aes-256-cbc -in $1 -out $1.enc -pass pass:apple
mv $1.enc $1
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to signal that the interpreter is receiving a file which is not a tar archive, yet it expects one. Have you checked to make sure the file your providing is a tar archive?